# WYGWAM caching images?

Tags: wygwam

I create an image and upload it to the server under a name, say Test Graphic A. Then inside WYGWAM, I click the picture icon, and choose Test Graphic A from the server. Everything is okay at that point.

Then, I correct a mistake in Table Graphic A in Photoshop, and use File Manager to delete it from the server, and then I upload the corrected version under the same file name, i.e., Test Graphic A.

Then, I go to WYGWAM and delete the old Test Graphic A, click the picture icon and choose (the corrected) Test Graphic A.

But, WYGWAM continues to use the old Test Graphic A. The only way I have found around the issue is to rename the corrected version, upload it again, and place it again.

This shouldn't be necessary. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EE caching or a third-party plugin for caching, or a caching service like CloudFlare? And are you making sure your local browser is set to never cache pages?

Caching issues almost always breakdown to a cache set not breaking. You should make sure all of your caches are cleared. WYGWAM is **not** caching your files, so the issue is systemic to a different caching solution that is currently working. Update with some answers to my question and I can expand.

Comment: I am new to all this, and don't know the answers to you questions except that it is not my browser caching. I am a writer adding content to a web site under contract. If you can tell me simple ways to find the answers to your questions, I will do so. Thanks.

Comment: Ooof... uhh, I can try and explain how to check some of these things, but if you're a content editor, I'm going to bet that you don't have the appropriate user privileges to check most of this stuff anyways. I suggest you contact your contractee and get back to us; you are welcome to point them directly to this stack question or quote my answer.

Comment: Okay, I will try to get the site guru to come here. Thanks.